# How to copy files selected from a txt file to another folder python

Tags: python

Folder A has more than 100 files, folder B is my destination folder. I want to copy 10 files in folder A to folder B. The 10 files names are in the text file C.

```
import os
import shutil
from glob import glob

namelist = open('/Users/C.txt').read().splitlines()
input = '/Users/A'
output = '/Users/B'
path = '/Users/A'
files = glob(path)

for path in files:
   filedir, filename = os.path.split(path)
   for filename in namelist:
     shutil.copy2(input,output)
```

It returns an Error. Please help me to do it in Python, thanks a lot!

Comment: What error is it returning?

Comment: What is the error? Can you share some example data? Please see: [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of things that you can do with your code:

```
import os
import shutil
from glob import glob

#namelist = open('/Users/C.txt').read().splitlines()
# context manager will take care of closing the file after open 
# no need read as one string and do splitlines, readlines take care of that
with open('/Users/C.txt') as fp:
    namelist = fp.readlines()
input = '/Users/A'
output = '/Users/B'
path = '/Users/A'
files = os.listdir(path)
# dont need glob import as you already imported os 
#files = glob(path)
# loop only through files mentioned in the text file and see if they are available in 
# folder A
for file_name in namelist:
    file_path = os.path.join(input,file_name)
    if file_path in files:
        dest_path = os.path.join(output,file_name)
        shutil.copy(file_path,dest_path)
#for path in files:
#   filedir, filename = os.path.split(path)
#   for filename in namelist:
#     shutil.copy2(input,output)
```

Comment: It's done. I add the suffix to the path, the files names have such suffix but the names in the list don't. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have sample data or error message to check. From what i can see in your code,

```
for path in files:
   filedir, filename = os.path.split(path)
   if filename in namelist:
     shutil.copy2(input,output)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your paths are from the root folder because of the starting forward slash. Try putting a dot in front of them if the folders and files are relative to the location of your .py file or no preceding slash:

`./Users/A` or `Users/A`